# Fazer cópia de elementos HTML pra dentro de um form

Tags: javascript, dom, eventos

Quero copiar o `div` clicado, pra dentro do `form` que ja contém o `select`.

De exemplo esta:

```js
        var opt = document;

        function processar(el) {
            opt.getElementById('minhaLista').innerHTML = el;
        }
```

```html
    <form name="form" id="minhaLista">
        <select>
          <option value="">A</option>
          <option value="">B</option>
          <option value="">C</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <hr size="1">

    <div id="vitrine">
        <div id="produto1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="processar(produto1)">
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.jpg" width="300" />
</a>
            <div>
                A
                <p>Exemplo 1</p>
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr size="1">

        <div id="produto2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="processar(produto2)">
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.jpg" width="300" />
</a>
            <div>
                B
                <p>Exemplo 2</p>
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr size="1">

            <div id="produto3">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="processar(produto3)">
                <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.jpg" width="300" />
</a>
                <div>
                    C
                    <p>Exemplo 3</p>
                    <span>3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

O foco principal é o elemento imagem [`img`], parágrafo [`p`] e texto [`span`].

O `select` deve permanecer dentro do `form`, sem remoção por parte do *script*.

Talvez o termo correto seja realizar uma **réplica** da `div` para o `form`.

Por demais simples que possa parecer, infelizmente não consegui.

Comment: Utilize a propriedade `outerHTML`, por ex: `opt.getElementById('minhaLista').innerHTML = el.outerHTML;`

Comment: O `el` é um objeto, por isso você não consegue adiciona-lo com `innerHTML` (exceto se você utilizar `outerHTML` ou `innerHTML` no objeto que deverá ser replicado).

Quanto a não substituir o `select`, você pode adicionar uma `div` dentro do `form` e, ao invés de utilizar `opt.getElementById('minhaLista')`, você utiliza `opt.getElementById('minhaLista_minha_div').innerHTML = el.outerHTML;`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Grato pela boa vontade e explicação assim como o link que me aponta.

Comment: Verifica isso: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/MXaEpo